# How to exclude a positive record on a related, but negative record in SQL Query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to make a query that checks to see if a user's value for [PaperlessBillingOptIn] is equal to "N" for a promotional email for a new feature.

However, because users can have multiple records in our database (attached to their policies), they may sometimes have one record with "Y" and one with "N."

In this case, we **don't** want to send to a user whose PaperlessBillingOptIn is "N" if they have another record for which it is "Y."

How can this be accomplished within an Automation Studio query activity? It seems like doing normal counts doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
select distinct
  m.emailAddress
, m.PaperlessBillingOptIn
from Policies_Master m
where m.PaperlessBillingOptIn = 'N'
and not exists (
  select *
  from Policies_Master m2
  where m2.emailAddress = m.emailaddress
  and m2.PaperlessBillingOptIn = 'Y'
)
```

Comment: I had thought to try something like this at first, but the Automation Studio queries don't support 'select distinct'

Comment: You _can_ `select distinct` in SFMC queries.

Comment: Ah. I had read somewhere that it didn't work.

In any event, when I replicate the above, I get the error:
"The multi-part identifier "m2.PaperlessBillingOptIn" could not be bound." Is there an additional step here?

Comment: Did you update the query to use the actual name of your data extension?  You didn't specify it in your question.